# Google Drive Client

Tags: linux, encryption, cloud-storage, google-drive

I am running Debian (SMP Debian 4.9.82-1+deb9u3) and am looking for a secure method to enable Google Drive Sync on my PC. As far as I am aware, there is [no native Google Drive client](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/06/google-drive-backup-and-sync-linux-support) for Linux, and are an array of [Open Sourced alternatives](https://www.fossmint.com/best-google-drive-clients-for-linux/).

The issue I am left facing is one of privacy and security. Granted, I'll be encrypting files on upload (and therefore, download) but need to know that the service/application I am using is reliable; if it is open source then it's got a fighting chance.

It would be wonderful if I could force an upload and encrypt at the same time, either via command-line or a native GUI.

Key required features:

- Allow both `pull` and `push` requests (i.e. Download and Upload);
- Available on Debian

Nice to have features:

- Open source and peer reviewed;
- Command line interface;
- Encryption functionality;
- Support for an application password (or token) as opposed to password;

Furthermore, it would be wonderful if some form of `symlink` existed, or I could have a `/home/$User/Google` folder for file-manager function.

I am looking at [Grive2](https://www.fossmint.com/grive2-google-drive-client-for-linux/) based purely off command-line functionality, but have not looked at the other options.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Insync](https://www.insynchq.com/) it has all your requiered features, CLI and GUI support and, supposedly, "Symlink, junction and alias", although I have never used that.

There is a free trial and a $30 one-time payment per Google account after that.

Comment: [Security](https://www.insynchq.com/privacy)
*We value your trust in providing us your Personal Information, thus we are striving to use commercially acceptable means of protecting it. But remember that no method of transmission over the internet, or method of electronic storage is 100% secure and reliable, and we cannot guarantee its absolute security.* I would like a product that clarifies itself a little more on it's means of privacy. Do you know if there is a forum anywhere with a little more info?

Comment: [InSync Security Page](https://forums.insynchq.com/t/faq-on-security/53) states it stores no files, but has info on your account name and quota levels. There is also a post discussing [how to use an internal browser to generate your own token](https://forums.insynchq.com/t/clarification-about-insynchq-servers/868/4).